# Where In mysql query

Tags: mysql, where-in

When you use a where in query such as...

```
SELECT 
ID, A, T
FROM `table1`               
WHERE (A,T)             
IN ($query)
```

Is there a way to have the result in the same order as your query?

So if the $query was ("David Crock", "Big Crocks"), ("Annie Smith", "My Life")

the result is ordered

```
342 David Crock Big Crocks
12 Annie Smith My Life
```

Comment: There is the `ORDER BY` clause, but generally speaking, databases do NOT guarantee that they'll preserve the order that data was inserted, unless you take measures to add some metadata to indicate that ordering yourself.

Comment: Most likely it will search top down from the first primary key to the last. So if your primary key is the ID, it will probably display results that way. I think, as @MarcB B said, using order by is your best way to control sorting.

Answer (score 2):

If $query is a SELECT statement then do join instead.

If it is a set of literal values then either insert them into a temporary table with some ordering such as an auto-increment id and do a join+order by or...

```
SELECT 
ID, A, T
FROM `table1`               
WHERE A             
IN ('David Crock', 'Annie Smith')
ORDER BY LOCATE(A, 'David Crock,Annie Smith');
```

(sorry - I've not come across a multi-valued 'IN' statement before hence unsure how it works - does it work?)

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah symcbean - multi-valued IN statements work really well. My application selects up to 5000 records at a time this way - I found it was the fastest way to select multiple specific records.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have to do this mapping in the application layer, it's the only place where you have all the relevant information. It's possible to sort it in the correct order using a `TEMPORARY` table, but this is best avoided.

Comment: Yeah - it's the mapping that's been tripping me up. I have a php array of records that I'm matching with the select data, but accents break things. If I do a select for "Monae" and "Monãe" is in the table, it hits. Then "Monãe" won't match against "Monae" back in my application, so it fails.

Comment: Do you want them to match or not?

Comment: Two scenarios - I want them to match when people use the app ie Monae will hit on Monãe etc, but I don't want them to match when the records are being created, as I need separate records for Monãe and Monae - so I can query the db for the record's id to use in further parsing. Currently, if Monãe is in there, Monae won't be created, the id and row data for Monãe is retrieved instead, and when my upload script looks for Monãe in the php array to append the id to, it can't find it (as Monae is in the array). I have a php workaround, but would rather deal with it at the database level.